# Trouble mixing min width and max width media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to mix both min width and max width media queries like so:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navibar li a {
    font-size: 8px !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .navibar li a {
    font-size: 2px !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1301px) {
  .navibar li a {
    font-size: 1rem !important;
  }
}
```

When hitting the 1300px the font size changes to 2px, but never hits the 768px media query. Why is this?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzWWqd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think why not? You specific the `.navibar li a` when `max-width: 1300px` is 2px, so form 0 to 1300px, they will have that value = 2px.
And since you write the rule of `max-width: 1300px` after the rule of `max-width: 768px`, so it always be 2px too even if you have less than 768px width. You should relocate the rule of `max-width: 768px` after the 1300 one and it will work just fine.
And a side note, try not use `!important` in your code, it a bad practice. Find other way(s) to override the rule(s), `!important` should only use to override inline style, which is a bad practice too if you write style like that.

Comment: ah so the higher widths need to be on top?

Comment: @thatemployee yes, like any other css, the same selector use the last attribute(s) you wirte

Comment: Another approach that you can do is add the min-width, like this for example `@media only screen and (max-width: 1300px) and (min-width: 769px) { YOUR CSS CODE }` and of course add it to the first media rule like this `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 320px) { YOUR CSS CODE }`, in that way you can make sure that media query will execute in those dimensions